# Exctract value from querydict

Tags: json, ajax, django, dictionary

I need to extract the value '180' as an integer from this output `<QueryDict: {'tz_data': ['180']}>`
the output is an ajax POST request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryDict is a subclass of dict.

```
request.POST['tzdata']
```

Note that this is fully documented as well as explained in the tutorial, which you should follow.

Comment: @Amir please remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem. This shows other users that you found a solution, and it earns reputation points for you and for the Daniel Roseman.